# Generalization of Euler $R\ge2r$

Tags: geometry, inequality

> Let $r$ be the inradius of $\triangle ABC$, prove that for any point $P$,
> $$(PA+PB+PC)(PA\cdot PB+PB\cdot PC+PC\cdot PA)\ge72r^3.$$

Notice that when $PA=PB=PC$ we get Euler inequality $R\ge2r$.

I thought of using the coordinate system. Let $I~(0,1)$ be the incenter, $B~(b,0)$ and $C~(c,0)$. So we can get $A~\left(\frac{b+c}{bc+1},\frac{2bc}{bc+1}\right)$ and $r=1$. Let $P~(s,t)$. We can express the inequality algebraically but there are too many square roots.

---

"Source" of this problem: firstly to generalize Euler inequality, I conjectured that $\sum PA\ge6r$, which is true since we only need to consider the Fermat point.

Then I considered other symmetric polynomials about $PA$, $PB$, $PC$. After a few attempts with geogebra, I made the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

**Some remarks.**

I think your idea is feasible. We can use some bounds to eliminate the root sign. I will update this answer if I make progress.

Let $I(0, 1)$ be the incenter,
$B(-u, 0)$ and $C(v, 0)$ where $u \ge v > 1$. Then $A(\frac{u - v}{uv - 1}, \frac{2uv}{uv - 1})$.

Let $P(s, t)$. Let
$$x := PA = \sqrt{\left(s - \frac{u-v}{uv - 1}\right)^2 + \left(t - \frac{2uv}{uv - 1}\right)^2},$$
$$y := PB = \sqrt{(s + u)^2 + t^2},$$
$$z := PC = \sqrt{(s - v)^2 + t^2}.$$

We need to prove that
$$(x + y + z)(xy + yz + zx) \ge 72.$$

Numerical experiment shows "at minimum" $s = 0, t = 1, u = v = \sqrt 3$.

Comment: What bounds have you got? I tried C-S but cannot succeed.

Comment: @youthdoo We may split into some cases (use different bounds for different cases). However, it is still complicated when we eliminate the root sign. I will update soon.

Comment: Have you had any more ideas?

Comment: @youthdoo I stopped just here.